# How get locale date in Django without locale class?

Tags: python, django

I have existing Django project and I need to get date formatted by locale other than default.

I don't want to use locale class because it will have effect on global parameter and it can has unexpected consequences.

Is there any common way to localize date without locale class or am I mistaken about how locale is work?

Comment: Do you need it in a template or in a view? Do you want your project to support multiple locales (is [USE_L10N](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#use-l10n) True or False)?

Comment: @Raz I need this in my view.
No, I don't need in multiple locales support, only convert date to string.
USE_L10N = false.

Comment: Than why can't you just write `format_date` function that calls `strftime` and call it where you need?

Comment: @Raz I didn't know about babel library, and I didn't found it when searched answer in google, great thanks!
It's work like a charm.

Comment: @Raz Sorry, I didn't understand you clearly at first time, anyway thanks for help, I wouldn't have found babel without your answer, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me so it's [babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/dates.html) lybrary.

Instead of using locale, that will have global effect:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> import locale
>>> d = date(2017, 2, 13)
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "de")
'de'
>>> print(d.strftime("%d %B %Y"))
13 Februar 2017
```

We can use babel and it will not change global `locale`:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> from babel.dates import format_date
>>> d = date(2017, 2, 13)
>>> print(format_date(d, format="d MMMM Y", locale='de_DE'))
13 Februar 2017
>>> print(d.strftime("%d %B %Y"))
13 February 2017
```

Comment: I didn't get that you want to translate month name. I meant that you could do just `d.strftime("%d %B %Y")`.